# JavaScript-free WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

Someone I know is looking for a WordPress theme suitable for the website of a small business or charity. These sorts of website typically have a blog (or "News" or "Updates") section, plus the following pages:

- Home (front page)
- About
- Contact
- Product A (or Project A)

  - Sub-product A1 (or Subproject A1)
  - Sub-product A2 (or Subproject A2)
- Product B (or Project B)

  - Sub-product B1 (or Subproject B1)
  - Sub-product B2 (or Subproject B2)

The theme **must *not* require visitors to have JavaScript enabled**. That is, it must either be completely free of JavaScript, or must follow the principles of "[progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)" or "degrading gracefully", e.g. through careful use of `<noscript>` elements.

Ideally, the theme would be [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=799237832#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms).

There are thousands of WordPress themes available, but finding one that meets these requirements is proving to be non-trivial.

Comment: Is a static site an option, rather than WordPress? JavaScript-free static sites have many advantages with regard to accessibility, ease of maintenance, etc., and certainly can provide what you need, with the exception of blog comments (if you want those).

Comment: @Kodiologist, I agree with you about the benefits of static sites. However, in this particular case the person concerned is familiar with WordPress and would prefer just to apply a suitable theme, rather than changing the way the site is built.

Comment: See also https://wordpress.org/support/topic/noscript-theme-tor-browser-safest-settings-no-javascript/